# VB export page to PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert aspx page to PDF. The output file is weird (include css script) 
[image]

code behind

```
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Imports iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

    Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        Me.Page.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub
```

How can to remove the css from output file and table format is not appropriate, original web page output is

[image]

Comment: Hi please change the Pagesize A4 to landscape

Comment: THAT IS NOT THE ISSUE

Comment: have you check that ?

Comment: the problem is css script is coming in output pdf and table size and font has changed .

Comment: ok. got it. You don't want css in output,right ?

Comment: yes and also output should be the same as above picture